# Dealing with neutered type hinting in Magento

Tags: error, exception

Just wondering if anyone has better strategies than I've thought of for type checking to co-exist with Magento's custom error handler. Specifically, I'm wondering about a "Catchable Fatal Errors" as thrown in the case of a typehinted parameter mismatch. Here's an example from the `Mage` class:

```
/**
 * Write exception to log
 *
 * @param Exception $e
 */
public static function logException(Exception $e)
{
    if (!self::getConfig()) {
        return;
    }
    $file = self::getStoreConfig('dev/log/exception_file');
    self::log("\n" . $e->__toString(), Zend_Log::ERR, $file);
}
```

Because of the error handler, anything can be passed to the method, including a `Zend_Date` (which will work fine, but look super confusing in your exception log), or a `Mage_Core_Model_App`, which actually will have a fatal error.

It's possible to re-implement type checking at the top of a method: `$e instanceof Exception` but such tactics defeat the purpose of a typehint.

Any <strike>hints</strike> suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Good question +1

Did some research and tests after a good point in the direction after my discussion with @mpw on my first answer. I partly misunderstood it the first time.

Will add some code to clarify so others understand the issue better.

### A note before take off

I never had such problems until this came up.
Developing in Magento with developer mode enabled I do not even think a second about this. So every time I *fart*, it will show up and will be corrected accordingly.

### The problem with a explaining sample

Your saying fatal errors will be logged(if enabled) and code will continue as usual because no error is thrown by `mageCoreErrorHandler` or the program will `exit`.

*First Magento's core error handler for uncatchable errors* `app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php`

```
/**
 * Custom error handler
 *
 * @param integer $errno
 * @param string $errstr
 * @param string $errfile
 * @param integer $errline
 */
function mageCoreErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    /**
     * Some internal logic here for building the error message
     */

    $errorMessage .= ": {$errstr}  in {$errfile} on line {$errline}";
    if (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
        throw new Exception($errorMessage);
    } else {
        Mage::log($errorMessage, Zend_Log::ERR);
    }
}
```

As you can see, in developer mode it will tell something useful, it throws a error. When turned off it will log(if enabled) and continue.

### The proof

My `testfile.php`

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

// Test function which expect Customer_Model_Customer
function test(Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
{
    var_dump('Do not show me because ' . get_class($customer) . ' is not a customer.');
}

// Enabled developer mode
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

// Put a var in here
$noGood = Mage::app();

// Make some context
var_dump('hello');
try {
    // Call test function with a not accepted var
    test($noGood);

    // Tell if we get here
    var_dump('And we are here!');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump('You should die, because I am doing something which I should not do');
}
```

### The result

Developermode enabled. **Correct result**

```
string(5) "hello"
string(66) "You should die, because I am doing something which I should not do"
```

Developermode disabled, **Incorrect result**

```
string(5) "hello"
string(61) "Do not show me because Mage_Core_Model_App is not a customer."
string(16) "And we are here!"
```

So it will eventually skip the error and continue on the next line of code.
Maybe with even weirder outcomes. (as @mpw points out)

### Conclusion

It **could** happen that someone is developing in a way that errors will go **unnoticed** and it **will** eventually give unexpected results.

Ofcourse when developing in a professional manner. Errors will **be** noticed and **attention** is payed.
The way to prevent this in Magento is always enabling developermode in a developer/test environment.

IMHO it should never get to this point of discussion, where checking a variable a second time(at least that's how I would describe it) is the way to go.
Code should be tested before releasing on production environments. It should **not** be needed.

### Second thoughts

Maybe Magento should stop after a fatal error. Or generate a report and show it to the visitor.
This way next lines of code will never be executed, and things will be noticed.

Comment: > Of coarse when developing in a professional manner. Errors will be noticed and attention is payed. The way to prevent this in Magento is always enabling developermode in a developer/test environment.
¶
I agree with that. My goal is to have Magento respect language rules in production mode. Looks like it'll require a custom module perhaps. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Maybe Magento should throw a exception in both cases. The user will be presented a Magento errorlog page and in var/exception will have a matching logfile, the same as regular exceptions. The great catch here is that code wont be executed without notice. You could copy the functions file to the app/code/local and always throw a exception

Comment: I've decided to mark this as the answer. Though I still think muffling errors like that is dangerous, it seems unlikely that there's a way to make sure Magento respects typehints without opening up other problems. The reminder to keep dev mode turned on is a good one for future readers, and that's the most important takeaway

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I think this is a general problem with `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR` in PHP.

What you have in your question is the exception handler, not the error handler. The error handler is causing the actual problem you discuss here with [*catchable fatal errors* (`E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`)](https://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-recoverable-error).

PHP 7 and HHVM have this already solved.

It's worse with Magento because the error handler does not deal with this since PHP 5.2 error class.

A more useful kind of error handling would be dealing with this error class and to turn these errors into **ErrorException**s. Example (not by me, [from  here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7#hard_to_catch)):

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if ($errno === E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) {
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
    }
    return false;
});
```

So in the light of Magento, the default error handler is the global function `mageCoreErrorHandler` in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php`. It get's registered via `Mage::app()` by the `init()` method of the **Mage_Core_Model_App** (`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php`) (via protected `_initEnvironment()` method).

An [observer on `controller_front_init_before`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/64971/4115) which registers your own PHP error handler on top should suffice then (error handlers in PHP are stackable):

```
$previous = set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) use (&$previous) {
    if ($errno === E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) {
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
    }
    if ($previous) {
        return call_user_func($previous, $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
    }
    return false;
});
```

*catchable fatal errors* then are turned into exceptions and you can deal with them in your own extension code *or* they are uncaught and will be seen in the exception log (instead of having your shop run gaga on wrong types like the current behaviour is, *dead programs don't lie*). In PHP 7 the exception to look for isn't **ErrorException** then but **TypeException** (which is a **BaseException**) for the now *catchable fatal errors*.

All other errors are passed on to the error handler of Magento.

Note: I have not tried this, it's a write-up but I know the problem you're asking about and the error handling analysis has been done against 1.5.1.0 and verified against 1.9.1.0 through code analysis. The error handler stacking should work. I append a little extended example code that demonstrates most parts working.

I have not yet packaged this as a magento extension but it should be straight forward with modman. I'll put it on github then.

### Appendix: Error Handler Demo

The following code-example ([online demo](https://eval.in/319636)) demonstrates the stacking of error handlers and exception throwing on *catchable fatal error*:

```
<?php
/**
 * error handler demonstration
 *
 * stackable error handle with previous call and catchable error exceptions
 *
 * @author hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com>
 * @link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64972/4115
 */

set_error_handler(function() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    var_dump("me is the previous error handler", $args);
});

$previous = set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) use (&$previous) {
    if ($errno === E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) {
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
    }
    if ($previous) {
        return call_user_func($previous, $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
    }
    return false;
});

$test = function(callable $test) {};

$a = $undefined; // provoke little warning

$test(new stdClass); // provoke catchable fatal error
```

**Program Output**

```
string(32) "me is the previous error handler"
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(8)
  [1]=>
  string(29) "Undefined variable: undefined"
  [2]=>
  string(45) "/tmp/execpad-0eca072b619d/source-0eca072b619d"
  [3]=>
  int(28)
}

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be callable, object given, called in /tmp/execpad-0eca072b619d/source-0eca072b619d on line 30 and defined' in /tmp/execpad-0eca072b619d/source-0eca072b619d:26
Stack trace:
#0 /tmp/execpad-0eca072b619d/source-0eca072b619d(26): {closure}(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/tmp/execpad-0e...', 26, Array)
#1 /tmp/execpad-0eca072b619d/source-0eca072b619d(30): {closure}(Object(stdClass))
#2 {main}
  thrown in /tmp/execpad-0eca072b619d/source-0eca072b619d on line 26
```

Comment: Excellent write-up. During your testing, was there a measurable performance degradation from re-setting the error handler?

Comment: I haven't so far. There is also a related area in core where on development mode all warnings / errors are converted to **Exception** (and not **ErrorExceptuion** - not even logged). This perhaps requires a patchset to fix this in a sane manner. For the error handler, there is no good dispatch method available, also here I somehow tend to patch core even to bring a fixed default error handler in.

Answer (score 1):

It is already handled by default PHP by adding `(Exception $e)` in the function parameter definition.

You cannot pass anything else to this function than a Exception or extend of Exception.

Comment: Take a look at the `mageCoreErrorHandler` function. An error triggered by incorrect params will be handled and and suppressed in non-developer mode, and throw an `Exception` in developer mode.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong when such happens in the first place. Magento has the `mageCoreErrorHandler` to be sure that visitors won't get a error thrown in their face. You could build a own `try{}catch(){}` to grab them yourself, and if you cannot pass them on.

Comment: Considering no exceptions are thrown in the case of a suppressed catachable fatal error, what would the try/catch get me?

Comment: I'm finally getting it, after a local test... You're very right, the error is suppressed and the code will continue. I'll update my answer and add some extra thoughts

Comment: I'll post a new answer otherwise our conversation makes no sense at all