# Store-Frontend: What is the first event that can be observed?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, magento-ee

With a current, vanilla Magento 1.9.1 (CE) or 1.14.1/1.14.2 (EE) what is the *first* event that can be observed?

- for the frontend (via `/index.php`; when the installer did run already)
- for the frontend, when the installer did not yet run (if it makes a difference)
- for the adminhtml
- in cron
- in webservice API 1
- in webservice API 2

(this question might be looking for pure facts, but more interesting in the scope of Magento 1 is how to find these events in code)

---

In process of finding out more, I've collect some web-resources:

- [What's the earliest event Magento dispatches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6410410/367456) (Q&A Jun 2011)
- [Magento Startup Events](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/32402056167/magento-startup-events) (Sep 2012; by Alan Storm)
- [What is the first event fired in Magento?](http://www.eschrade.com/page/what-is-the-first-event-fired-in-magento/) - (Apr 2014; by E. Schrade)

Comment: For the frontend I found so far `controller_front_init_before`  (if the request is not cached).

Comment: And I found `resource_get_tablename` as well but it's somewhat dirty. Via Magento Hackathon PSR-0 Autoloader https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader/blob/master/app/code/community/Hackathon/PSR0Autoloader/etc/config.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to observe these events yourself as follows:

/app/Mage.php modify the `dispatchEvent()` function as below:

```
/**
 * Dispatch event
 *
 * Calls all observer callbacks registered for this event
 * and multiple observers matching event name pattern
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param array $data
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_App
 */
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true); //add this line
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

Now when you run the page, you'll notice that `/var/log/events.log` logs every event, in order, when loading whichever page you're interested in observing.

Make sure that this is performed in a staging environment where you are the only person using the site, to ensure you're logging the correct events.

Clean out the log file after observing each page individually so that the first event logged is always the first event fired.

Comment: Nice, I had a similar idea this morning, thanks for sharing the code. So +1 for the moment :) - an adoption could set a static flag and *only* log the first event into the log so it's easier to review across different requests.

Comment: This is also what [Alan Storm suggested in an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6411728/367456) he also puts in there some findings. I'll ran this as well against the current versions later on.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem, or provide some further feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the ping. Does the first event differ on pages? Or is it more with cron, adminhtml or frontend?

Comment: After applying these code i got resource_get_tablename as my first event am i write or not?